# My bash script isn't printing anything. More specifically it is not entering the if loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement, scripting

I am attempting to print only odd numbers 14 thru 49. However, I seem unable to enter the if loop and no numbers or my "Inside if" statement is printing.

I included print statements to see what is happening within my code. When code is run, the statement "Inside for loop" prints 4 times, which is the expected amount of times the for loop would iterate. So my for loop is working fine. However, based on the fact that neither numbers nor "Inside if" is printed. I am not entering my if loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( count=14; count<=49; count+=5 ))
do
        echo "inside for loop"

        if [ $(($count%2)) -ne 0 ]; then
                echo $count
                echo "inside if"
        fi

        let count=$(($count+5))
done
```

I was able to accomplish this with a while loop, using the same logic and if statement, so I am unsure why it isn't behaving as I expect:

```
#!/bin/bash

let count=14

while [ $count -le 49 ];
do
        if [ $(($count%2)) -ne 0 ]; then
                echo $count
        fi
        
        let count=$(($count+5))
done
```

My assignment requires me to use the for loop. Please help and thank you!

Comment: 15 is between 14 and 49 and is odd. Why do you increment by 5?

Comment: that's what the assignment wanted.

Comment: Don't mix arithmetic and non-arithmetic operators for your numeric operations. You're using arithmetic operators `(( ... ))` in some parts of your code so use it for all of your comparisons too, i.e. `if (( (count%2) != 0 ))` and `while (( count <= 49 ))`.

Answer (score 2):

You're doubling up on `count = count + 5` since you're doing it inside the `for` expression and at the end of the loop. Therefore you're adding 10 per loop, which means count will never be odd.

Remove `let count=$(($count+5))` in your first script and it will work as expected.